# Value too great for base

Tags: bash, date

I'm trying to display how long it takes for my script to execute in both seconds and milliseconds.

This is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

before=10#`date +'%s%N'`
sleep 1
after=10#`date +'%s%N'`

echo "$before"

let "time_taken=$before-$after"



echo "$time_taken"

echo "$s"
```

But I get the following error:

```
./tijdsmeting.sh: line 9: let: time_taken=10#1590683503N: value too great for base (error token is "10#15906835
~                              |03N")
```

I researched it and it has something to do with decimal/octal/... But I did specify it needed to be decimal by using `#10`. Maybe using `ibase`? And my errortoken isn't `08` like in the other cases on the internet..

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that your system's `date` implementation doesn't support the `%N` format specifier, and is rendering it as literal `N`?

Comment: Ohwww that could be possible.. I'm using a Mac.

Comment: Indeed, you can see the `N` in the error message there. In base 24, `N` would be a valid digit... As an aside, I don't think you should need `10#` here, the output of `date +%s` should not have leading zeroes (unlike months, days, hours and minutes often have)

Comment: If you're just interested in the duration in seconds, investigate bash's `$SECONDS` variable.

Comment: Run it under the bash built-in time command: gives you `real 0m3.740s`. You may need some inventive subshelling to capture it.